# Using Magento resize vs uploading already resized images

Tags: magento-1.9, image-resizing

We have custom magento review module that have lots of 70x70 image icons which when clicked load big images.

Currently we manually resize them and upload 2 version of files - big image 640x480, and icons 70x70.

Are we getting any performance boost from this comparing to using magento resize function?

As far as i understand we improve website performance only for the first visit of the page(cause we already resized files for magento), and after cache is build it's exactly same thing speed wise.

p.s. it takes too much time to resize and upload 2 version of files, so would like to use magento resize functionality if there is no loss in site speed.